# How to setup Corda Node for Production?

Tags: spring, continuous-integration, corda, production

After checking some examples and tutorials I wonder if there is a guide how to start a productive Corda Node.

I would expect something like a docker(compose) with Message Server, DB and Web Server (Spring ???) to start the whole infrastructure which enables deployments of new CordApps or updates.

Anyone here who could share a e.g. Jenkins pipeline which could act as blueprint ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general steps of deploying a Cordapp.

1. Install the Corda Node
2. Implement the Corda Firewall PKI
3. Generate Bridge and Float keystores for your the Artemis server (message queue)

You can take a look at this official guide for a detailed explanation.

And if you are working on Docker, there is a guide available now [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/docker-image.html).

For CI/CD, there is a few samples already been done with Jenkins on in the Corda github. Besides you can look at CircleCI for an alternative option